# Want to enable PARALLEL and NOLOGGING on Oracle Delete statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, parallel-processing

I have a very huge table with more than 3.5 billion records that increases 500K each day, I want to delete all records before year 2014. Every delete command I run, after few hours fall into error state, so I am looking at doing this job faster, last command I run was:

```
DELETE /*+ PARALLEL (8) */ FROM XYZ WHERE YEAR <= 2014;
```

After 744 minutes I get

> ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server

I guess if I could run the DELETE command with both PARALLEL and NOLOGGING, switch maybe I could do this, but I don't know how to run the session in NOLOGGING state and at the same time enable PARALLEL for the command, also I know we can run

```
DELETE /*+ NOLOGGING PARALLEL (8) */ FROM XYZ WHERE YEAR <= 2014;
```

But as I find in somewhere, it seems that with this command PARALLEL hint will be ignored.

Please advise on how to run the  DELETE command both in PARALLEL and NOLOGGING

Comment: You should have a tree of exceptions. What is the inner exception?

Comment: If possible, `CREATE TABLE TMP <options> AS SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE YEAR > 2014`, recreate appropriate constraint, indexes, grants, etc. and then drop the original table and rename TMP to the original name. When doing so, you can create the table partitioned on YEAR so next time you can drop historical data instantly.

Comment: And my guess for the inner exception is "Cannot allocate more space in UNDO tablespace" :-). Btw. NOLOGGING is not a hint but an option for DDL statements. That's why delete is mostly the heaviest operation for the database. It needs to log all the row data. Only INSERT can avoid the logging when using APPEND (or PARALLEL which makes APPEND implicitly)

Comment: @Husqvik - I agree that a table of 3,5bn rows ought to be partitioned on date.  However, Partitioning is *a chargeable extra* to the Enterprise Edition license, and hence not cheap.  You should not make the recommendation without mentioning the licensing issue.

Comment: @APC - Ok, thanks for mentioning that :-).

Comment: @FlorinGhita ,  I don't know what is the inner exception, but I guess that could be due to lack of space.

Comment: @Husqvik , thanks for your comment, I already know about creating new table and removing old one, but that's a solution to whole problem, I need an answer about enabling PARALLEL and NOLOGGING at same time.

Comment: your problem is the undo, not redo. Not logging won't help. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not logging the delete operation won't help too much. There is really small amount of things to be redone for a delete operation.

The problem here is a huge amount of undo(It contains every row deleted in order to be inserted in case of error/rollback).
Also, parallel just speed up things, don't change the amount of undo.

I see here two solutions/workarounds:

1. increase the undo tablespace.(talk with your dba)
2. delete in smaller chunks.(for example, delete 4 months, commit, then again 4 months, commit again, etc.)

**UPDATE**: Now I'm a little unsure about my statement above about redo. Because writing in undo **will** generate redo. However, the longest part of the execution of your delete is the rollback because you hit an exception(it may be 2/3 of the time). Splitting the task in 3-4 chunks may be faster than your failed query.